# Why does 'undeclared mutex' error show up when it is declared in struct?

Tags: c, mutex, semaphore

I am creating a producer and consumer files using semaphores for synchronization. I created a structure where I define the sem_t variables. One of the sem_t variables is mutex. Mutex stands for mutual exclusion. However, I get an error when I compile my code saying that 'mutex' undeclared. This doesn't make since to me since I thought I was declaring it in the struct.

I have tried initializing the variable to the value 1 and using other methods to use the variable in, like sem_wait() and wait().

```
#define BUFFER_SIZE 10
typedef struct{
    int buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    int in;
    int out;
    sem_t mutex;
    sem_t cnt_filled;
    sem_t cnt_empty;
} shm_structure;
```

```
/* pointer to shared memory object */
shm_structure *ptr;

ptr->in = ptr->out = 0;

    fp = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    //cnt_empty = 
    //mutex = 1;

    do {
        /* produce an item in next_produced */

        while(((ptr-> in + 1) % BUFFER_SIZE) == ptr->out) {
            ; // do nothing
        }

        wait(cnt_empty);
        wait(mutex);

        if(fscanf(fp, "%d", &item) != EOF) {
            ptr->buffer[ptr->in]= item;
            printf("%s Read %d from the file\n", get_time(), item);
            ptr->in = (ptr->in + 1) % BUFFER_SIZE; //increment tell the end of the file
        } else {
            break;
        }

        /* add next_produced into the buffer */

        signal(mutex);
        signal(cnt_filled);
        //sem_post(mutex);
        //sem_post(cnt_filled);

    } while(1);

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
```

My code should have no errors when I compile it. That is the only result I am looking for at the moment.

Comment: You should be accessing it from an instance of that struct.

Comment: Like the error says, you have variables (`cnt_empty`, `mutex`, `cnt_filled`) but don't define them anywhere in the code you posted. Also, `signal()` and `wait()` have nothing to do with semaphores...

Comment: `ptr` is presumably a pointer to a `shm_structure`. You probably want to use its fields instead of independent variables.

Comment: Change `wait(cnt_empty);` to `wait(ptr->cnt_empty);` and `wait(mutex)` to `wait(ptr->mutex);`.

Comment: @JohnBode I'm not sure `wait` and `signal` are the actual functions they will want to be passing `sem_t` arguments into.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons: Probably not, but the OP just wants the code to compile at this point.  Logic errors come down the road.

Comment: The code compiles without errors. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

When you declare a struct, you are defining an aggregate data type.  Now you need to create an instance of this struct, and then you can access the members of the struct.  For a basic example of how to use struct members:

```
typedef struct{
    int x;
    int y;
} my_struct;

my_struct my_instance_of_struct;
my_instance_of_struct.x = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you. That solved the undeclared mutex problem. However, do you know why I know get 'incompatible types in assignment' error? ```my_instance_of_struct.mutex = 1 ``` seem to be compatible because it is just a variable in the struct using the struct instance.

Comment: I recommend you look at Shawn's comments to your question, which points out that `ptr` is probably a pointer to an instance of your struct.  After that, I would recommend reading up on the documentation for POSIX semaphores.  My answer isn't intended to really cover the usage of semaphores specifically, but the accessing struct members.

Answer (score 0):

```
    signal(mutex);
```

You get an error here because `mutex` is not declared. Rather you have to do `shm_structure.mutex`.

Comment: "*Rather you have to do `shm_structure.mutex`.*" well, no. And I am sure you know. Please be more accurate when answering.